# strtod is returning 0

Tags: c, string, double

I've been working on this project that deals with an input file that looks like the following:

```
A 0.0345
B 0.3945
...
Z 0.2055
```

Basically, I'm reading each line, after reading the line, I want to pull **only** the double out of the string. I'm trying to use `strtod()` and everyone's examples seem to use it perfectly fine but in my example, it only returns 0.

Here is my code:

```
for (count = 0; count < 26; count++)
{
    char buffer[100]; /* Buffer for the line read by fgets */
    char *letters; /* Stores the string calculated by strtod */
    double relFreq = 0.0;

    if (fgets(buffer, 100, stream) != NULL)
    {
        relFreq = (double)strtod(buffer, &letters); /* Since the format is A 0.0000, we're just grabbing the double */
        *(sampleOne + count) = relFreq; /* Add the relFreq to the array */
    }
}
```

Through the use of a debugger, `buffer` has the correct data, for instance `A 0.0345\n` but when `strtod()` returns a value it's always 0. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not used to any of these functions (I don't use C), but maybe you're giving " 0.0345" instead of "0.0345" (with leading space)?

Comment: or just use fscanf to make life a bit simpler?

Comment: **Don't cast** if you don't have to (and can explain explicitly why you have to and why it's right)! Also, if you don't use the endptr from `strtod` (for example to check for errors), don't ask for it: Pass 0.

Comment: @Deduplicator the cast was an attempt to get it to work, I'll delete it right now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the first character is non-numeric, `strtod` should be returning `letters` equal to `buffer` (the first character is invalid), indicating that nothing has been read.

You should be able to fix this by passing `&buffer[2]`, where the number starts:

```
relFreq = strtod(&buffer[2], &letters);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Dxp1FJ)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think that [`strtod`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtod.html) will ignore the leading letter on your lines, but it will not.  You'll need to do something like this:

```
relFreq = (double) strtod(&buffer[1], &letters);
```

And since you are not using `letters`:

```
relFreq = (double) strtod(&buffer[1], NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sscanf`. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *s = "A 0.0345\n";

    char c;
    double d;

    sscanf( s, "%c %lf", &c, &d );

    printf( "%f\n", d );

    return 0;
}
```

The output os

```
0.034500
```

As for your code then you could at first to find a digit in the buffer and apply function strtod to the pointer that points to the found digit provided that the first field in the buffer is always a non-digit.